# How to parse SOAP response in PHP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have cracked my head the last few days trying to parse a soap response (via curl command-line), but I can not get it to work. I just want to get the object value of `ResourceIdentifier` which is **rs-1304500829200-200**. I am using PHP 5.3.x

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:deliverMDRecordsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://mdstore.data.dnetlib.eu/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <return>
        <ns3:Address>http://129.70.12.20:8282/dnet-mdstore/services/MDStoreResultSet</ns3:Address>
        <ns3:ReferenceParameters>
           <ResourceIdentifier:ResourceIdentifier xmlns:ResourceIdentifier="http://www.driver.org" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">rs-1304500829200-200</ResourceIdentifier:ResourceIdentifier>
       </ns3:ReferenceParameters>
        </return>
     </ns2:deliverMDRecordsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>

<?
 $response=<<<END ....soap response here... END; 

 $xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('t', 'http://www.driver.org'); 
 foreach ($xml->xpath('//t:ResourceIdentifier') as $item)    
 { //  print_r($item);       
     echo $item->asXML();    
 }    
?>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What is the output of your `print_r`s?

Comment: Why CURL and not http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php ?

Comment: If you're posting up XML, it's a good idea to format it using xml starlet or something similar first for the sake of readability: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/ - if you're using a *nix such as one of the BSDs, a Linux distro, MacOS, Solaris, &c., it ought to be packaged, and I'd be surprised if it's not.

Answer (score 4):

You should really be using the built in [SoapClient class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) if you can, or if you can't, use the [PEAR SOAP libraries](http://pear.php.net/package/SOAP). As you're running PHP 5.3, SoapClient ought to be available.

On the issue of your use of Xpath, you're querying against the wrong namespace and element. The namespace of the element you're querying is "http://www.driver.org", thus this should work, though keep in mind that I haven't actually ran it, though it should be correct:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response); 
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('rid', 'http://www.driver.org');
foreach ($xml->xpath('//rid:ResourceIdentifier') as $item) {
    echo (string) $item; 
}
?>
```

But please don't do that, use one of the two SOAP clients I mentioned. I've no idea where you got `{http://apilistener.envoyservices.com}payment` from as it's not mentioned in the response.

Comment: That downvote was harsh! I can't see anything in my answer that could possibly justify it.

Comment: I removed my down vote before your comment as I saw your edit. Clear your cache :) I forgot the leave a comment earlier describing the down vote. You weren't addressing the question and just commenting.

Comment: That's cool. I've got into the habit of starting with an admonishment against people going down the wrong track first, and then, if they're absolutely set on continuing with their plan, tell them what's going wrong. I don't see comments as being somewhere you talk to people about the question they asked (formatting, phrasing, details) rather than anything answer-ish, and I'd class telling the person to use a well-tested library as being the latter.

Comment: Accepts as awesome. :-) Any chance you could share with us your reason for not using a SOAP library? SoapClient is going to be as fast as anything you could possibly write in PHP.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show that if you stringify a SimpleXMLElement with a cast, you'll get the element's text.